# Updating Google web app front end part way through script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a web app that on button click initiates a script and populates the return value in a span, similar to below:

**page.html**

```
<button id="btn">Run function</button>
<span id="result_span">
    <!--return value from doStuff goes here-->
</span>

<script>
    document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",init_function);

    function init_function(){
      console.log('init')
      let updateLocation = document.querySelector('#result_span')

      function onFailure(error){
        let warning = `<span style="color:red">${error}</span>`;
          updateLocation.innerHTML = warning;
      };

      function onSuccess(element){
        let result = element;
        updateLocation.innerHTML = result;
      };

      google.script.run.withFailureHandler(onFailure)
        .withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
        .doStuff();
    }
</script>
```

**code.gs**

```
function doStuff(){
    //do stuff
    return string;
}
```

This is working correctly, but how can I update the front end UI as the script runs. For example, something like:

```
function doStuff(){
    //do stuff
    update-the-user-part-one
    //do more stuff
    update-the-user-part-two
    //do even more stuff
    return string;
}
```

Unfortunately `console.log('update-the-user-part-one')` doesn't go the front end, but perhaps there is some way using callbacks or promise to have `<span id="updates"></span>` innerHTML update during the script.

Comment: Are you asking how do you update data in a spreadsheet or a document?

Comment: @Cooper neither, I want to pass a value/string to the front end ie `element.innerHTML`

Comment: So you want to access the google ui?

Comment: @Cooper I want to access page.html live in the browser. The user initiates the script, and then during the script, the page updates with progress info.

Comment: I thought you said that was already working.

Comment: @Cooper The end return value is successfully going back to the front end when the script completes, but during the script I want to provide a progress updates to the front end (like 'some stuff has been done', 'more stuff has been done').

Comment: I'm not understand what your saying because doStuff() is a server side function.  You could return and hmtl string to the success handler thought

Comment: Yeah I see what your saying but I think once you return something to the success handler that shuts it down for any further messages.  At least that's what I think.

Comment: @Cooper What I want to do is run a script from the front end and for update messages to be sent to the front end. At the moment I am only able to return a single value at script completion

Comment: I never have been interested in doing that myself because most operations I deal with get done rather quickly.  But I suppose you can do that but the interaction has to alway start on the clientside so you could maybe set it up to run on setInterval.

Comment: @Cooper setInterval wouldn't work in this case as I only want to send specific messages after particular things have occurred in the script but good idea.

Comment: Well the function that setInterval calls could always check a message queue to see if there are any outgoing requests.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is realtime update on the site during the script's execution, I wasn't able to find any references or resources to make it work.

Although, I was able to somewhat simulate what you want below. This approach might not be optimal, but this will still achieve what you want (in appearance).

Assuming this is your function:

```
function doStuff(){
  // do part 1 then update site
  updateTheUserP1
  // do part 2 then update site
  updateTheUserP2
  // do the last part and return the final value
  string = "done all";

  return string;
}
```

I propose you separate your function into multiple functions depending on when you want the site updated. So I decided to divide it into 3 parts

```
function updateTheUserP1(){
  string = "done 1";
  // assuming part 1 finishes after 1 second
  Utilities.sleep(1000)
  return string;
}

function updateTheUserP2(){
  string = "done 2";
  // assuming part 2 finishes after 1 second
  Utilities.sleep(1000)
  return string;
}

function doStuff(){
  string = "done all";
  // assuming the last part finishes after 1 second
  Utilities.sleep(1000)
  return string;
}
```

Then you'll want your calls in the client side to cascade:

```
function do1(element){
  updateLocation.innerHTML = element;
  google.script.run.withFailureHandler(onFailure)
    .withSuccessHandler(do2)
    .updateTheUserP2();
};

function do2(element){
  updateLocation.innerHTML = element;
  google.script.run.withFailureHandler(onFailure)
    .withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
    .doStuff();
};

function onSuccess(element){
  let result = element;
  updateLocation.innerHTML = result;
};

google.script.run.withFailureHandler(onFailure)
  .withSuccessHandler(do1)
  .updateTheUserP1();
```

#### Output:

[image: output]